# how to send a GET request using two send functions?

Tags: c++, sockets

This code is sending a `GET` request with the help of one send function
but I want to send the same `GET` request, but break it down and send it using two send function. The code is given below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>//the new file.
#include<unistd.h>//for using the sleep function.
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    //first we will do thigns with only one thread.
    char* address;
    address=argv[1];
    int network_socket;
    network_socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port=htons(80);
    //now we will set the ip address of the required field.
    inet_aton(address,(struct in_addr*)&server_address.sin_addr.s_addr);
    int connection_status=connect(network_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&server_address,sizeof(server_address));
    if(connection_status){
            cout<<"error in the setting up the connection"<<endl;
    }
    /*
    now since we want to mimic the http we will first send
    a request and then we will accept the reply.

    main question?
    -> how to construct a request ??:)
    */
    char request1[]="GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    char response[4096];
    send(network_socket,request1,sizeof(request1),0);
    recv(network_socket,&response,sizeof(response),0);
    cout<<response<<endl;
    close(network_socket);
    return 0;
    }
    /*
      but i want something like this
      char request1[]="GET /index.ht";
      char request2[]="ml HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
      send(network_socket,request2,sizeof(request2),0);
      send(network_socket,request2,sizeof(request2),0);

      */
       //but doing this will make server give 400 error
```

Comment: if we can't do this can anyone explain why?

Comment: Did you send `request2` twice in your code or is it a typo in the post?

Comment: Your code is not C but C++. As these are very different languages, please pick tags carefully.

Comment: If you get a 400, you sent the wrong data, so spin up Wireshark and find out what you're really sending, then present a [mcve] that has isolated the bug. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with your approach.

Comment: ... in fact you _should_ be checking how many bytes were actually sent and potentially pushing the remainder in subsequent `send` calls. You can't assume that everything will be pushed out from one `send`. Read the manpage...

Comment: Artyer its  a typo (sorry :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the following part of your code:

```
char request1[]="GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
send(network_socket,request1,sizeof(request1),0);
```

..for example with this way:

```
char request1a[]="GET /index.html";
char request1b[]=" HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
send(network_socket,request1a,sizeof(request1a)-1,0);
send(network_socket,request1b,sizeof(request1b),0);
```

Note the `-1`. It is needed, because you don't want to send extra '\0' to the server. Using `strlen()` could be alternative way.

TCP is stream oriented, so several sends won't add any message boundaries to the transmitted data. It may generate more IP-packets, but it won't break the functionality.

Remember to add error checking for those function calls.